# Why does opening a file with TCL work on LINUX but not Windows?

Tags: windows, file-io, tcl

I am running a TCL script with Pointwise to smooth a mesh, and need to see a field variable plotted. To do the plotting, I have to use a second code, in this case Tecplot. However, to get data out of Pointwise, I have to use `puts` and an I/O channel. My code looks like:

```
proc GetIJCellSizeLimits {dom} {

    global mincell cwd

    set io [open cwd/mincell.dat {RDWR CREAT}]

    set iPts [lindex [$dom getDimensions] 0]
    set jPts [lindex [$dom getDimensions] 1]
    set numPts [expr {$iPts * $jPts}]

    set points [Range 1 $numPts]
    set minCell 1000.0
    set maxCell 0.0
    set rmsCell 0.0
    set numCells 0

    foreach pnt $points {
    ...
    }
    puts $io "$xpt $ypt $zpt $mincell($pnt)"
    flush  $io
    close $io
}
```

The `...` is a bunch of computing to evaluate the statistics of a mesh, and find the minimum cell size attached to a point `$pnt` to be stored for later use and for output to be evaluated because the mesh exceeds 1000 points.

Every time I try to open a file, using the same constructs as I do with LINUX, the Windows platform says *couldn't open "cwdmincell.dat": permission denied*. How do I open a file on Windows, and can it be done without **tcom**?

Comment: If `cwd` is a variable that contains a path prefix that you want to join "mincell.dat" to, you should use `[file join $cwd mincell.dat]`.

Comment: Where is $cwd?  If it is blank, then it tries to create the file in C:\.  Not all users have permission to create files in C:\ - you normally need to be an admin user to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the directory separator: Tcl handles `/` on any platform as the directory separator.

This is about the file permissions [*] of the directory you're trying to write to

```
C:\Users\jackman\tmp>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.431]

C:\Users\jackman\tmp>tclsh
% info patchlevel
8.6.4
% set fh [open ./newfile {RDWR CREAT}]
file2627a80
% puts $fh first
% puts $fh second
% close $fh
% set fh [open ./newfile r]; puts [read $fh]; close $fh
first
second
ond line

% set fh [open /not_allowed_here w]
couldn't open "/not_allowed_here": permission denied
```

Observations:

1. I can create a file in my home directory
2. I cannot create a file in the filesystem root directory
3. Note the contents of the file has more than 2 lines: this is because the file has previous contents, and the list of access directives did not include `TRUNC`.

[*] I'm not a windows sysadmin: "file permissions" I'm sure is not the right term for it. ACL maybe?

Comment: It is also possible that Pointwise has the file open, and the attempt to open it for writing will fail.   Windows always reports "permission denied" when it should be reporting "file in use".

Comment: According to the file permissions of the folder, I have full access. And if the file were already open, I'd be able to write to it, yet I cannot.

Comment: No, you don't have it open, Pointwise has it open.   And windows doesn't always allow multiple processes to open the same file.   I have no idea what rules windows uses to determine this.   e.g.  sometimes I can use notepad on a log file, other times, I can't use notepad, but can copy the log file to a new file.